# How to groupBy object using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using ReactJS. I have an object which looks like this:

```
{
  autumn=firstContactPersonName: "John",
  autumn=firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
  autumn=secondContactPersonName: "Jhonny",
  autumn=secondContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
  christmas=firstContactPersonName: "Tommy",
  christmas=firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
  christmas=secondContactPersonPhone: "Thomas",
  winter=firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
  winter=firstContactPersonName: "Peter",
  winter=secondContactPersonName: "Tom",
  winter=secondContactPersonPhone: "44664455"
}
```

How can I group them based on `autumn`, `christmas`, `winter`. So one object with `autumn` have the `autumn` fields, the second one `christmas` have the `christmas` field, and the third one `winter` have the `winter` fields?

And so on. All fields will have a segment name before `=`, so I can easily see what kind of segment they belong to.

Comment: You might want to fix the server so it produces something more useful instead of adding a work-around on the client.

Comment: Sorry, but your input object structure doesn't possible in JS

Comment: I know its bad, but i am helping a friend of mine and he cant change anything, he need to work with this data coming in :/

Comment: In the output `data` is currently an array. However you follow this up with key/value-pairs. My guess is that `data` should be an object instead. However it's also possible to move the key inside the object `"season": "autumn"`, and remove the keys from the `data` (keeping it an array). As it stands the output is not valid, could you fix this in the question?

Comment: the objects you specified do not have valid syntax. For the input: object keys must be enclosed in quotes if they contain special characters. In the output you specified an array data: [ ... ]  which does not have named properties ("autumn") (as stated in 3limin4t0r's comment).

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for my bad explaination. But i want tom sort them in their own groups.

Comment: `Object.entries()`/`Object.keys()` + `Array.prototype.reduce()` + any of the "group array of objects" questions here on SO

Comment: @3limin4t0r I suggest keeping it an array with the season property as the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable with pure JS, no need for lodash (which I'm not familiar with).
This function takes every property of your input object, splits the key around the equals sign for the season part (prefix) and rest (appendix). Afterwards it looks for an object in the output array with the same season and adds the properties to it. If there is no object with specified season, it creates a new one.

```
function processData(inputObj) {
    var data = [];
    for (var key in inputObj) {
        var prefix = key.split("=")[0];
        var appendix = key.split("=")[1];

        var dataObject = data.find(o => o.season == prefix);
        if (!dataObject) {
            dataObject = {season: prefix};
            data.push(dataObject);
        }
        dataObject[appendix] = inputObj[key];
    }

    return { data };
}
```

produces this output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "season": "autumn",
            "firstContactPersonName": "John",
            "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
            "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
            "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644"
        },
        {
            "season": "christmas",
            "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
            "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
            "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas"
        },
        {
            "season": "winter",
            "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
            "firstContactPersonName": "Peter",
            "secondContactPersonName": "Tom",
            "secondContactPersonPhone": "44664455"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How does it works for you? On me it says that `ob` is undefined? Did you miss something?

Comment: sorry, it's a bug, will fix it ASAP. Edit: fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can produce your groups by looping over the keys in the object. Split the key on `=` and capture the results. The first element should be the group, the second the property to access within this group.

Create a new object if a group doesn't yet exist. Then set the property within the group equal to the value of the original object.

```js
const input = {
  "autumn=firstContactPersonName": "John",
  "autumn=firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  "autumn=secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
  "autumn=secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  "christmas=firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
  "christmas=firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  "christmas=secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas",
  "winter=firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  "winter=firstContactPersonName": "Peter",
  "winter=secondContactPersonName": "Tom",
  "winter=secondContactPersonPhone": "44664455"
};

const output = {};
for (const key in input) {
  const [season, property] = key.split("=", 2);
  if (!output[season]) output[season] = {};
  output[season][property] = input[key];
}

console.log(output);
```

I find my explanation a bit confusion, but I hope that combined with the code snippet you understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` to generate an array of [key, value] pairs, and iterate with `Array.reduce()`. For each pair, split the key by `=` to get the group key, and the value key, create the group's object if none exists, and assign the value to the object.

```js
const data = {"autumn=firstContactPersonName":"John","autumn=firstContactPersonPhone":"46442644","autumn=secondContactPersonName":"Jhonny","autumn=secondContactPersonPhone":"46442644","christmas=firstContactPersonName":"Tommy","christmas=firstContactPersonPhone":"46442644","christmas=secondContactPersonPhone":"Thomas","winter=firstContactPersonPhone":"46442644","winter=firstContactPersonName":"Peter","winter=secondContactPersonName":"Tom","winter=secondContactPersonPhone":"44664455"}

const result = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    const [gKey, key] = k.split('=') // get the key
    
    r[gKey] = r[gKey] || {} // generate the object if it doesn't exist
    
    r[gKey][key] = v // assign the value to the object
    
    return r
  }, {})

console.log(result);
```